# R statistical package: wrapping GOFrame objects

Tags: r, statistics, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I'm trying to generate GOFrame objects to generate a gene ontology mapping in R for unsupported organisms (see http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/GOstats/inst/doc/GOstatsForUnsupportedOrganisms.pdf).

However, following the instructions literally doesn't help me.
Here's the code I execute (R 2.9.2 on ubuntu koala 64 bit)

```
library("AnnotationDbi")
library("org.Hs.eg.db")
frame = toTable(org.Hs.egGO)
goframeData = data.frame(frame$go_id, frame$Evidence, frame$gene_id)
goFrame = GOFrame(goframeData, organism = "Homo sapiens")
```

However, when i try to map my dataframe into a goFrame object, I get this mistake

```
Error: could not find function "GOFrame"
```

I'm pretty sure the GOFrame wrapper is in the AnnotationDBI library, so I'm puzzled.
Any help is extra appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's your R version. GOFrame wrapping is described to be supported in the bioconductor AnnotationDBI only since the latest release.

I just tried it and it works with R 2.10.0

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

As per the [package description](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/AnnotationDbi.html), the `Go.db` package is only suggested rather than depended upon. Hence, a simple

```
 library(GO.db)
```

seems to be what you need to do.

Comment: Nah, it's still not loading it. The method seems to be only in R 2.10.0 version!

Comment: I doubt it is the R version but BioC has this habit of relating their release to the R versions.  So maybe not R 2.10.0 per se -- but given R 2.10.0, the (implied) version of AnnotationDBI then works ?